# Is there a way to scale an avi using ffmpeg while keeping the videos alpha channel?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, transparency

I have been trying to change the scale of an *avi* but also keep the alpha channel. Also the video needs to open in *after effects* but when I try to open it I get the error below. I have this running in a for loop to work for all the videos in the folder.

```
ffmpeg -i %%X -vf scale=!newWidth!:!newHeight! -pix_fmt bgra -r 24 -c:v rawvideo "resized\%%X"
```

It seems to work but when I try to test the alpha channel in After Effects I get the error below:

> The item has an `unlabeled alpha Channel`....

If I select the Straight-Unmatted (option).....

I get the error:

> After Effects error:(error(4) reading frame from file (86::2)

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to `encode` the movie twice. Once converting it to a `mov.` and then converting it using copy codec to an `avi`.

If anyone has a simpler solution please let me know :)

## Convert to MOV with appropriate scaling...

```
ffmpeg -i %%X -vf scale=!newWidth!:!newHeight! -c:v qtrle "%%~nX.mov"
```

## Copy codec converting to an avi saves transparency...

```
ffmpeg -i %%X -vcodec copy "resized\%%~nX.avi"
```

Comment: Thank you for some reason that was not working either. It would make the video background opague. I noticed rawvideo leaves the transparency correct when making a video from a png sequence though o_O. Weird stuff xD.